# CSS Layout not taking with id but does with <li> tag

Tags: html, css, layout, format

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div id="tp-nb">
    <ul>
        <div id="tp-ls">
            <li>
                account-icon
            </li>
            <li>
                notification-icon
            </li>
            <li>
                icon
            </li>
            <li>
                Images
            </li>
            <li>
                Gmail
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

And here is the CSS part:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300pxx;

}
li{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

When I change the css (li) to the id "#tp-ls" it loses it's layout and bunches all up completely. I've tried changing it from id to class, but as I figured out, made no difference.

Is there any possible way of handling a groupe of

without affecting ALL

? I'm sure there is, however I fail to understand how it's possible. I also lack the knowledge thereof to know what I"m looking for, and therefore don't know how to search it on google ( for those of you whom would reply with "google it". )

Thank you, and until I get a response I'll continue searching what i'm searching for.

Comment: You can't put a <div> inside a <ul>....  add the id to the <ul> instead

Comment: Ignoring the structure - you don't have any `li` that has `id="tp-ls"`, so when you change the `css` from `li` to `#tp-ls` there is no `li` element that this `css` will be applied to

Comment: Instead of using float ,try to look into flex for such tasks. source:[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/),happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you make some mistakes

- You must not use `div` inside `ul`
- You can see that `tp-ls` this id is not assigned to any `li` so you have to give this id in `ul`

Example

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300pxx;

}
#tp-ls li{
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tp-nb">
    <ul id="tp-ls">
        <li>
            account-icon
        </li>
        <li>
            notification-icon
        </li>
        <li>
            icon
        </li>
        <li>
            Images
        </li>
        <li>
            Gmail
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Hope this will helps you :)

Comment: OMG!!!
I didin't know that rule!
Thank you so much for the quick and amazing response!
Thank you thank you!!